# Can anyone explain this function definition above the switch statement?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, calculator

Here, I've made a function, that takes a character array and a single element array as input.
The input of expression is like "56+78", and then someone suggested this approach of using ascii code and for loops to store the two "numeric" substrings as two numbers, and used the character and switch statement below. But, I don't understand the part of storing these substrings as numbers and the asciicode concept.

```
void calculate(char ch[], char op[]){
    int i;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    for(i=0; ch[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if((int)ch[i]>=48 && (int)ch[i]<=57){

            num1 = num1*10+(((int)ch[i])-48);
        }
        else{
                op[0]=ch[i];
                break;
    }}
    i++;
    for(; ch[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if((int)ch[i] >= 48 && (int)ch[i] <= 57){
            num2 = num2*10+(((int)ch[i])-48);
        }

    }
    cout<<"OUTPUT: ";

    switch(op[0])
    {
    case '+':
        cout<<num1 + num2<<endl;
        break;
    case '-':
        cout<<num1 - num2<<endl;
        break;
    case '*':
        cout<<num1 * num2<<endl;
        break;
    case '/':
        cout<<num1 / num2<<endl;
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at an ascii table and check what character range is represented by the values 48 to 57. That should make things more clear.

Comment: Magic numbers... 48 is ASCII for zero... 57 is ACSII for nine.  It's a character string to integer conversion

Comment: That should be `if (isdigit(ch[i]) num1 = num1 * 10 + ch[i] - '0';`. No hard-coded assumptions about character sets, no magic numbers. But that code doesn't handle bad input, like someone typing in "3a4".

Comment: Those two loop that convert the input text to numeric values are identical, except for the variable that they modify. Write a function that does this, so you only have to write the code once.